# Coerce a vector to another type in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

In R, you can coerce between vector types using `as.X`, e.g. `as.character(1)` or `as.integer(1)`. However I can't work out if there is a native, elegant way to do the same in Rcpp.

Firstly, the C API does have an `AS_CHARACTER` macro which I tried to use, but Rcpp doesn't seem to include `Rdefines.h` where it's defined:

```
> as_character = Rcpp::cppFunction("CharacterVector as_character(RObject x){ return AS_CHARACTER(x); }")
file113af2570bd06.cpp: In function ‘Rcpp::CharacterVector as_character(Rcpp::RObject)’:
file113af2570bd06.cpp:6:49: error: ‘AS_CHARACTER’ was not declared in this scope
    6 | CharacterVector as_character(RObject x){ return AS_CHARACTER(x); }
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:178: file113af2570bd06.o] Error 1
g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/migwell/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/Rcpp/include" -I"/tmp/RtmppCAKV8/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.10"    -fpic  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-LhKvHL/r-base-4.2.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c file113af2570bd06.cpp -o file113af2570bd06.o
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

If I try to use `CharacterVector`, it also fails to compile:

```
> as_character = Rcpp::cppFunction(
+ "CharacterVector as_character(RObject x){ return CharacterVector::create(x); }"
+ )
In file included from /home/migwell/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Vector.h:50,
                 from /home/migwell/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:40,
                 from file113af65cda53c.cpp:1:
/home/migwell/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/converter.h: In instantiation of ‘static SEXPREC* Rcpp::internal::string_element_converter<RTYPE>::get(const T&) [with T = Rcpp::RObject_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>; int RTYPE = 16; SEXP = SEXPREC*]’:
/home/migwell/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/generated/Vector__create.h:84:34:   required from ‘static Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE, StoragePolicy> Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>::create__dispatch(Rcpp::traits::false_type, const T1&) [with T1 = Rcpp::RObject_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>; int RTYPE = 16; StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage; Rcpp::traits::false_type = Rcpp::traits::integral_constant<bool, false>]’
/home/migwell/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/generated/Vector__create.h:71:26:   required from ‘static Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE, StoragePolicy> Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>::create(const T1&) [with T1 = Rcpp::RObject_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>; int RTYPE = 16; StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]’
file113af65cda53c.cpp:6:72:   required from here
/home/migwell/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/converter.h:49:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(const Rcpp::RObject_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>&)’
   49 |                         std::string out(input) ;
      |
```

On the other hand, it does allow `Rf_coerceVector` which does work, but it seem unlikely this is the best way, because I'm fairly deep into pure C if I'm using `STRSXP` and `Rf_` functions:

```
> as_character = Rcpp::cppFunction(
+ "CharacterVector as_character(RObject x){ return Rf_coerceVector(x, STRSXP); }"
+ )
> as_character(1)
[1] "1"
```

What is the most natural/simple way to do this in Rcpp?

I'm using:

- R 4.2.3
- Rcpp 1.0.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a second and closer look at the existing Rcpp documentation as provided by the ten vignettes, including two introductory ones and one focussed entirely on the conversions you ask about here, then you may encouter the two *central* helper functions `wrap()` to return any option to a `SEXP`, and `as<T>()` which (as a templated function) converts *from* a `SEXP` to the template type.

```
> cppFunction("CharacterVector cnvrt(NumericVector x) \  # indented for display
                   { return as<CharacterVector>(x); }")  # else really one line
> cnvrt(1.23)
[1] "1.23"
>
```

The thing that happens and is confusing is that the compiler most often automagically injects an existing conversion from or to `SEXP`, but it sometimes errors, or conflicts with other templated meta programming code (which is complicated, sadly).  For example overloading the `return` statement often bites us.

So I have some time-honoured rules:

- if in doubt, separate the out the assignment (and trust the compiler to re-optimise)
- for conversions, maybe first explicitly go from your source object to `SEXP` and then from `SEXP` to your destination object
- in other words "make it work first, then *maybe* make it fancy"

Comment: Thanks, great answer! You may not appreciate this, but I skipped the vignettes because they were only in PDF format which I find very difficult to read (column layout, not responsive like HTML, can't use my browser shortcuts), and skipped to HTML sources such as https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/index.html, http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html and https://gallery.rcpp.org/. I couldn't find this information there. My genuine feedback is that it would be great for people like me (and more Google-indexable?) if these vignettes were in HTML.

Comment: I expanded a little on the answer with an edit while you wrote yours.  And no, pdf it will be but thanks for asking.  It's all open source so if you want to build yourself a local html version the good news is you can.  I have been around html since the very early 1990s and quite frankly prefer the formatting guarantee I get from pdf.

Comment: And no, I do not appreciate that you skipped _all_ the documentation we provide and expect to be spoon fed here.  That is not how it works.  We are all adults, and you can choose to handicap yourself any way you want (and Teuder's manual is great) but by _explicitly ignoring_ available documentation you will only come so far.  I appreciate the honesty, it will save me ten minutes each time going forward as I may prefer to spend time answering question from you.  That was only half serious:  go and get yourself a pdf reader you like, and use what it out there.

Comment: Okay, for future reference it seems that https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf is the vignette that explains this in detail. I likely skipped this one because the name "extending" did not evoke "converting/coercing" to me. Hopefully this stack overflow question will instead point future users to this vignette.

Comment: And the vignettes _are_ dense and not easy to read.  We try, but docs _are_ hard.  And these basic conversions are of course also in _the_ intro vignette which as a published and peer review paper also exists in other forms for you (hint, hint). (Though in fairness only in one sentence, not a full example but there is only so much we can do in ten pages -- that intro _is_ good.  Please do read it.)  Or you could buy the book which is a slightly more polished version of most of the vignettes.